# How to get Product Collections with filter attribute value in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get product collection with filter by attribute Color(code) with value Black(5). I have one configurable product with color Black(5), Red(6).
Here Product Name Product 1(configurable product), Product 1 Black (simple product), Product 1 Red (simple product).

So I get the resulting Product 1 Black (simple product) but I want to result from Product 1(configurable product).

So please let me know the code for this.
My code is

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();               
$categoryProducts = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

$categoryProducts->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => '5'));
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $i.'==='.$product->getId().'==='.$product->getName();
    echo "<br>";
    //$i++;
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this below code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();               
$categoryProducts = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

$categoryProducts->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => '5'));
$categoryProducts->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$categoryProducts->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $i.'==='.$product->getId().'==='.$product->getName();
    echo "<br>";
    //$i++;
}
```

UPDATED :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $categoryProducts = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

        $categoryProducts->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => 5476));
        $categoryProducts->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $categoryProducts->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('link_table' => 'catalog_product_super_link'), 'link_table.product_id = e.entity_id',
            array('product_id', 'parent_id')
        );

        $categoryProducts->getSelect()->group('link_table.parent_id');

        foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo $product->getParentId() . "====" . $product->getName(); // Parent Id and name
            echo "<br>";
        }

        foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo $product->getId() . '===' . $product->getName();
            echo "<br>";
        }
```

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: So no product comes. please check it.

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: still, child product comes not parents

Comment: $product->getParentId() => It will return parent id. Please check it. I tested and it's working fine

Comment: okay got it, so do you mean I need to use that.

Comment: Yes......In My updated answer. Check first foreach loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107616/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code

```
<?php

namespace NameSpace\FilterProducts\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as CategoryCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;


/**
 * For FreshDeals
 */
class FilterProducts extends AbstractProduct
{


     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var Visibility
     */
    protected $catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * @var CategoryCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $categoryCollection;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $categoryFactory;

    /**
     * @var Category
     */
    protected $category;



    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        Data $helper,
        CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollection,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        Category $category,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->category = $category;


        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * get collection of FreshDeals Products
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProductCollection($categoryparams = null)
    { 

        $productCount = $this->helper->getProductCount();
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        if ($categoryparams) {
            $collection->addCategoryFilter($categoryparams);
        } else {
            $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
            if (!empty($category)) {
                $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
            }
        }

        $collection->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)->setPageSize($productCount)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('color', 'value of your attribute')

            ->setOrder(self::SORT_ORDER_FIELD, self::SORT_ORDER_VALUE);

        return $collection;
    }


}//end class
```